# Handler freezing GUI Android

Tags: android, asynchronous, android-handler

I am having some problems while implementing a asynchronous task. I would like to have a background task running in an activity for periods of time (15 minutes but for debugging purposes I am using 10 seconds).

My code:

```
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            ApplicationData.LoadApplicationData(getApplicationContext()); //Like SystemClock.sleep(2000)
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        try{
            Fragment currentFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentcontent);
            if(currentFragment != null) {
                FragmentTransaction fragTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fragTransaction.detach(currentFragment);
                fragTransaction.attach(currentFragment);
                fragTransaction.commit();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
        }
        finally{
            handler.postDelayed(this, 10000); //900000
        }
    }
},10000);
```

This code freezes the app for 2-4 seconds. The ApplicationData.LoadApplicationData loads data from the server and it takes that time. In my first attempt I was creating a thread so this work gets done asynchronously but then I could not update my fragment.

How could I update the background data, once it is done update the GUI?

Comment: use asyncTask to load from server...

Comment: Maybe you should consider using background service or multi threading

Comment: ApplicationData.LoadApplicationData is an List of Callables so it runs asynchronously but I need to wait for them to finish. Only after they all get done I update the GUI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                ApplicationData.LoadApplicationData(getApplicationContext());//background thread code
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            //the other foreground thread
                        }
                    });
                }

    }).start();
```

Comment: @azizbekian yes but UI will not be blocked

Comment: Any idea how can achieve the loop with this code? Have to run this in periods of 15 minutes. Is while and sleep reliable?

Comment: @Exprove , use AlarmManager to charge some event for a long period.

Comment: @Exprove , what the goal of your timer? If you use foreground app and UI  is opened by user you can use TimerTask. If you wanna charge any event to fire ti in the background you have to use AlarmManager. In other cases Android OS will kill your process.